# How would I make a system that hides the DIV on click with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I was making a web page.  It has this fixed side bar that hides on click...

I have two little smaller DIVs designated for the hide and close (`sideBarClose` , `sideBarOpen`)

When they are clicked, they do as specified at hiding the main div.

I want this done with pure JavaScript, not jQuery or something else.

Comment: set the elements `style.display` to `"none;"`

Comment: Why you dislike my post?  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you're quite new to JavaScript.  It would be better to do it with jQuery, but since you're wanting JavaScript:

I would do something like this,

```
<script>
function hide()  {
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("sideBarOpen").style.display = "inline";
}

function unhide()  {
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("sideBarClose").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Then, in your html:

```
<div id="sideBarOpen" onclick="unhide()"></div>
<div id="mainDiv">
   <div id="sideBarClose" onclick="hide()">
</div>
```

NOTICE!  Make sure in your styles you have `sideBarClose`'s display set to none:

```
#sideBarClose  {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: One sec, let me test it out.

Comment: Yeah, no problem.  It's a pretty basic question.  I would recommend researching a little before asking.